# Getting the month and day from a TimeStamp

Tags: java, android

I have a String timeStamp in this format "Wed, 29 Jan 2014 20:14:15 GMT". I want to be able to compare this date with another date that is in this format 01/25/1999. I have tried simpledateformatter but with no success.

```
String a = connection.getHeaderField("Last-Modified"); //Returns Wed, 29 Jan 2014 20:14:15 GMT
Date lastModDate = new Date(file.lastModified()); //returns 01/25/1999
```

This is the simpleDateFormatter I tried implementing

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter;
Date dateIn = null;
formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy", Locale.US);
try{
dateIn = (Date)formatter.parse(a);

}catch(ParseException e){
e.printStackTrace();
}
Log.d(TAG, "The server date is formated to : " + dateIn);
```

The dateIn is always null.

I want the to be able to do something like this

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/mm/yyyy");
Date strDate = sdf.parse(valid_until);
if (new Date().after(strDate)) {

}
```

Comment: Your title does not match your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following code...you will get the problem right.

```
Calendar calender = Calendar.getInstance();
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

String timeStamp = formatter.format(calender.getTime());
Date strDate = formatter.parse(timeStamp);

String currentTimeStamp = formatter.format(new Date());
Date currentTime = formatter.parse(currentTimeStamp);

if (currentTime.after(strDate)) {

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't know what you tried but this should work:

```
String a = connection.getHeaderField("Last-Modified");
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z", Locale.ENGLISH).parse(a);
```

This can help http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: Okay I see my error, I was not aware of "java.util.Date and java.sql.Date"

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that you are using the wrong date format for your formatter. If the date you receive looks like

```
"Wed, 29 Jan 2014 20:14:15 GMT"
```

Then you should use the following format

```
formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z", Locale.US);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `Calendar` class and its subclass `GregorianCalendar`. For exampe, to get the month of your date:

```
Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
cal.setTime(date);
cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
```

Comment: I tried this but if the date is in the format as such" Wed Jan 29 15:14:15 EST 2014". The code above will return 0 for some reason?